# C++ storing value inside struct member

Tags: c++

Hi I'm currently studying C++ and am quite new to this. I have a question for storing values read from csv file into a struct member variables.

I have to read the csv file line by line and parse it and store the values to member variables of a struct.

I can get the code to work till reading the csv file and parsing but I have trouble storing them into the member variables. I tried overloading based on what I learnt in school but I'm honestly lost on how this works.

```
struct TickData {
   std::string ContractName;
   double BestBidPrice;
   double BestBidAmount;
   double BestBidIV;
   double BestAskPrice;
   double BestAskAmount;
   double BestAskIV;
   double MarkPrice;
   double MarkIV;

   friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, TickData& obj);
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, TickData& obj)
{
   is >> obj.ContractName >> obj.BestBidPrice >> obj.BestBidAmount >> obj.BestBidIV >> obj.BestAskPrice >> obj.BestAskAmount >> obj.BestAskIV >> obj.MarkPrice >> obj.MarkIV;
   return is;
}
```

Above is the struct that has been given in the question (there are more variables but I cut it because it was too long) and below is my implementation:

```
int main()
{
std::string filename = "Ticker.csv";
std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string line, word;
std::ifstream input_file(filename);

TickData data;

while(std::getline(input_file, line)){
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    while(std::getline(iss, word, ',')){
        lines.push_back(word); // to store the parsed data into an array
        std::istringstream iss2(word);
        iss2 >> data;
        data.print();
    }
}
```

I get weird numbers like the one below instead of the actual data from the csv which should have ticker names(BTC,ETH) and prices etc,. When I print the lines vector, it shows the data correctly.

input data: BTC-24JUN22-200000-P,0.1,0.1,0,0,0,0,4.4616,111.09

what it should contain: BTC-24JUN22-200000-P 0.1 0.1 0 0 0 0 4.4616 111.09

what it shows from data.print(): 02473e-314-4.68831e+2173.02473e-3142.14859e-314043482290002.14821e-3143.02473e-3142.1486e-3144.94066e-3243.02473e-3143.02473e-314-8.78027e-25903.02473e-3142.14821e-3143.02473e-3143.02473e-3143.02473e-314-4.68831e+2173.02473e-.

data.print() is just a function to print the stored data. Would anyone have an idea how to overload the data correctly? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Any error message building or run-time? What exactly doesn't work? Help us help you.

Comment: sorry I think I was unclear about the issue, I amended the post.

Comment: What do you think `while(std::getline(iss, word, ','))` does?Might I suggest you print `word` and then consider how a full extraction of a `TickData` can come from *that*. I suspect you need to move the comma-separation to the `TickData` extractor. rather than here.

Comment: That's much better. But can you also add at least one line from the file you're reading? The actual input data.

Comment: @deLock Hi! I added the input data first line for reference. It's essentially the values that it should contain but with "," as it comes in a csv format

Comment: @cppnewbie Have you tried the solution in Sedenion's answer?

Comment: @deLock yes I have but sadly it still yields the same result :( I'll keep looking for more possible ways to solve this! thanks alot :)